# Where to get VMware-viclient?

Tags: vmware

Where Can I download the VMware-viclient?

Comment: https://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/vc41/ZHcqYmRoaGpiZHRAag==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/vc50/dHRAYnQldEBiZHBqaA==
- Sign in/register
- Agree to the terms
- Click the VMware vSphere Client download link. It's 351MB.